# email_verified_at automatically set while sending verification email in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWiPA.png)in my laravel app, i have problem that is when i register user laravel automatically fills email_verified_at column in user table and redirects to dashboard. it automatically verifies without clicking on link. I do not know why this is filling this column value while sending verification email.

this is register controller

```php
protected $redirectTo = 'email/verify';
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'alpha_num', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }
     protected function create(array $data)
     {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),

        ]);
    }
```

this is user model

```php
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password'
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

this is verification controller

```php
use VerifiesEmails;

   protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('signed')->only('verify');
        $this->middleware('throttle:3,1')->only('verify', 'resend');
    }
```

this is route file

```php
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::group(['prefix'=>'dashboard','middleware' => ['auth','verified']],function () {

    Route::get('/','dashboard\DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard-home');
});
```

this is login controller

```php
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers{
      logout as performLogout;
    }

 protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';
 public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        $this->middleware('prelogoutaction',['only' => 'logout']);
        $this->middleware('postloginaction',['only' => 'login']);
    }

    public function logout(Request $request){

      $this->performLogout($request);
      return redirect()->route('web-home');
    }
}
```

both email_verified_at and created_at are same.
please help...

Comment: Can you show us the code ?

Comment: yes i have showed up the code, please help

Comment: What have you wrote on `postloginaction` ?

Comment: because there is no issue in whatever you have posted here.

Comment: in this class i wrote nothing.

Comment: this class still has no code

Comment: this is empty middleware

Comment: sir you can check in image both time are same

Comment: ok then the last question have you created the table or simply run the `php artisan migrate`

Comment: Kindly check that is on update attribute is set for that column or what ?

Comment: yes on email_verified_at column there is extra ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()

Comment: kindly make it blank

Comment: Show us your database migration that creates the `email_verified_at` column, please.

Comment: $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->boolean('is_verified'); // bit type 0=not verified 1= verified
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at');
            $table->char('account_type',1); // bit type
            $table->timestamps();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after all the discussion over comments and after seeing the code
we can conclude that the issue is on the database end which set the verification date and it is automatically filled up because of the attribute `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` whenever the record is created.